# How do I get 'Run as Server' option for Spring Web MVC project in Eclipse STS?

Tags: java, spring, eclipse, maven

I tried running a Spring Web mvc project, but it only shows option to run as Java application and not run on server.
[You can see project facet is already checked(one of the solution in similar question)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jDfSo.png)

pom.xml file content:
[pom.xml](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LibAJ.jpg)

Comment: Have you set up any server runtimes in the preferences? What are you clicking on that only shows Run as Java Application?